# Auto shutdown of MySQL

Tags: mysql

Today morning, I found that mysql service was not available. It was working fine previously.

Please guide me what could be the possible reason for this. After I reinstall MySQL server, it worked again.

here i found the error log:

> 120409 16:48:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>   120409 16:48:47 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number
>   147932368753 120409 16:48:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 2 events
>   120409 16:48:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with
>   id 1 120409 16:48:49 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.5\bin\mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.5.18-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) 120413  3:20:08 [Note]
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Normal shutdown
>
> 120413  3:20:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Killing the scheduler thread,
>   thread id 1 120413  3:20:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Waiting for the
>   scheduler thread to reply 120413  3:20:10 [Note] Event Scheduler:
>   Stopped 120413  3:20:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 2
>   events 120413  3:20:12  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

Comment: Patch tuesday, windows update :-p

Comment: You should take a look and windows application/system event log also

Comment: @rkosegi, I checked as correctly pointed, Windows Update was installed just before, the service crash. I would like to know the reason behind that, as this was a production server.

Comment: @Tung, yes Windows update was installed just prior to that, but whats the reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for your service shutting down:

- Windows Update (most likely)
- Power outage (unlikely, or else you would not see "Normal shutdown" in the logs)
- Someone issued a shutdown on the machine

You mentioned that you re-installed your MySQL server, which leads me to believe that your original service could not start up.  MySQL is usually very good about logging **why** it cannot start up, a piece of important information that you have not included for us.  I only mentioned Windows update to point out an external force that **may have** affected your MySQL installation, and to also give a possible (but probable) explanation as to why your service went into shutdown.