# mysql server curious mistake and shutdown

Tags: mysql

My `mysql server` has a curious mistake and shutdown auto and I don't know what happened. how can I fix it?

### Error:

```
Version: '5.6.22'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
151214 10:30:12 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
151214 10:30:12 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
151214 10:30:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /srv/app/mysql/data/li630-151.pid ended
151214 11:20:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /srv/app/mysql/data
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Warning] The option innodb (skip-innodb) is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2015-12-14 11:20:27 12517 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@li611-43' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2015-12-14 11:20:28 12517 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-12-14 11:20:28 12517 [Note] /srv/app/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.22'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
151214 11:22:01 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
151214 11:30:23 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
151214 11:30:23 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
151214 11:30:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /srv/app/mysql/data/li630-151.pid ended
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136867/auto-shutdown-of-mysql

Comment: It might be because of a corrupted data file. If one(or more) of your mysql data files are corrupted, for example for unexpected power outage, or OS crash, then when mysqld tries to read/write from/to that file, then mysql process terminates. See if you can start the service manually and can select from each table individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by low memory on the server.